# Single Query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

How to calculate (score/no of question) in laravel/mysql/php single query

```
+=============+     +=============+    +===============+
|    User     |     |    Taken    |    |    Answers    |
+=============+     +=============+    +===============+
|     id      |     |   taken_id  |    |   answer_id   |
+-------------+     +-------------+    +---------------+
|     name    |     | user_id(FK) |    |  taken_id(FK) |
+-------------+     +-------------+    +---------------+
                    |  taken_date |    |  question_id  |
                    +-------------+    +---------------+
                                       |     choice    |
                                       +---------------+
                                       |      score    |
                                       +---------------+
```

I tried following:(I got scores of user_id from 2 tables Taken and answer)

```
SELECT a.user_id, answers.score FROM (
    SELECT MAX(taken.taken_id) AS taken_id, taken.user_id FROM taken 
    GROUP BY taken.user_id ) a, answers 
WHERE a.taken_id = answers.taken_id 
AND answers.score IS NOT null
```

But how to use User table details in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a join to user table to get the details of user

```
select u.id,
       u.name,
       a.score 
from (
    select max(taken_id) as taken_id, 
    user_id 
    from taken 
    group by user_id
) t
join answers a on t.taken_id = a.taken_id 
join user u on u.id = t.user_id
where a.score is not null
```

To get the sum of score for each user you can use following

```
select u.id,
       u.name,
       sum(a.score) score
from (
    select max(taken_id) as taken_id, 
    user_id 
    from taken 
    group by user_id
) t
join answers a on t.taken_id = a.taken_id 
join user u on u.id = t.user_id
where a.score is not null
group by u.id,u.name
```

Comment: Thanks M Khalid Junaid..
One more Question:
I got result like that : 
id name score taken_id  
28  John Doe  12  36
28  John Doe  12  36
28  John Doe  10  36
28  John Doe  15  36
37  sssss  12  38

How to calculate sum of score of each user (28/37)

Comment: Thansk @m khalid junaid
I cannot do this : sum(a.score) score 
Because score have comma separated scores (2,3 )
I think I have to do in (laravel)php only

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
DB::raw('select a.user_id, answers.score from (select max(taken.taken_id) as taken_id, taken.user_id from taken group by taken.user_id) a, answers where a.taken_id = answers.taken_id and answers.score is not null
');
```

Make sure you have imported DB class.